# I need to input txt file into javascript and then show a table with the information on the txt file

Tags: javascript, html, html-table, txt

I'm just starting into programming and I received that assignment, I have this txt file:

```
nombre="Mario";
apellido="Atencio";
cedula="8-782-2289";
telefono="233-7867";
correo="matencio@misitio.com";
nombre2="Roberto";
apellido2="Icaza";
cedula2="8-582-2149";
telefono2="393-5517";
correo2="ricaza@miweb.com";
```

and I need to first input it and then turn it into a table; I was able to create the input and reading of the text with this code:

```html
<input type="file" id="file-input" />
<h3>Contenido del archivo:</h3>
<pre id="contenido-archivo"></pre>
</head>
<script>
function CargarClientes(e) {
  var archivo = e.target.files[0];
  if (!archivo) {
    return;
  }
  var lector = new FileReader();
  lector.onload = function(e) {
    var contenido = e.target.result;
    mostrarContenido(contenido);
  };
  lector.readAsText(archivo);
}

function mostrarContenido(contenido) {
  var elemento = document.getElementById('contenido-archivo');
  elemento.innerHTML = contenido;
}
document.getElementById('file-input')
  .addEventListener('change', CargarClientes, false);
</script>
```

But it only shows me what's on the txt file, so I tried changing the txt file into the variables, like this

```html
<script>
var apple=2;
var nombre="Mario";
var apellido="Atencio";
var cedula="8-782-2289";
var telefono="233-7867";
var correo="matencio@misitio.com";
var nombre2="Roberto";
var apellido2="Icaza";
var cedula2="8-582-2149";
var telefono2="393-5517";
var correo2="ricaza@miweb.com";
</script>
```

And when I run it and input the txt file, it doesn't show anything, so I guessed that is reading it as variables, but I don't know how to put them into a table. I only know how to make a table on HTML like this:

```html
<style>
  table {
    width: 80%;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    box-shadow: -18px -8px 20px #ccc;
    margin-left: 13%;
  }
  
  tr {
    width: 100%;
  }
  
  td {
    background: transparent;
    width: 10%;
    border-top: 1px solid #003;
    border-right: none;
    border-left: none;
    font: 62% Arial, Helvetica;
    padding: 6px;
    text-align: right;
  }
  
  th {
    font: 62% Arial, Helvetica;
    background: #8ADBFE;
    color: #FFFFFF
  }
  
  .phpcolor {
    text-align: center;
    background: #CBCBCB;
    color: #BDEBFE
  }
</style>
<table cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0>
  <thead>
    <th>Nombre</th>
    <th>Apellido</th>
    <th>Cedula</th>
    <th>Telefono</th>
    <th>Correo Electronico</th>
    <tr>
      <td class='phpcolor'>Huron</td>
      <td class='phpcolor'>SD</td>
      <td class='phpcolor'>1281</td>
      <td class='phpcolor'>100</td>
      <td class='phpcolor'>-30</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class='phpcolor'>Rapid&nbsp;City</td>
      <td class='phpcolor'>SD</td>
      <td class='phpcolor'>3162</td>
      <td class='phpcolor'>106</td>
      <td class='phpcolor'>-30</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

(the table has to be on some specific colors), the issue comes because if I mix the two parts of the code, I can see the button to input files, but the table is already there (that's why I haven't tried to use the variables on the table). So basically I need that the table appears after the txt is input, using the variables that are in the txt file. I don't even know if the code I used is correct, or if I need to make the table a different way.

This is what I came up with

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="generator" content="CoffeeCup HTML Editor (www.coffeecup.com)">
  <meta name="dcterms.created" content="Tue, 17 Nov 2020 04:16:07 GMT">
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="keywords" content="">
  <title></title>
  <style>
    table {
      width: 80%;
      border: 1px solid #fff;
      box-shadow: -18px -8px 20px #ccc;
      margin-left: 13%;
    }
    
    tr {
      width: 100%;
    }
    
    td {
      background: transparent;
      width: 10%;
      border-top: 1px solid #003;
      border-right: none;
      border-left: none;
      font: 62% Arial, Helvetica;
      padding: 6px;
      text-align: right;
    }
    
    th {
      font: 62% Arial, Helvetica;
      background: #8ADBFE;
      color: #FFFFFF
    }
    
    .phpcolor {
      text-align: center;
      background: #CBCBCB;
      color: #BDEBFE
    }
  </style>
  <input type="file" id="file-input" />
  <h3>Contenido del archivo:</h3>
  <pre id="contenido-archivo"></pre>
</head>
<script>
  function CargarClientes(e) {
    var archivo = e.target.files[0];
    if (!archivo) {
      return;
    }
    var lector = new FileReader();
    lector.onload = function(e) {
      var contenido = e.target.result;
      mostrarContenido(contenido);
    };
    lector.readAsText(archivo);
  }

  function mostrarContenido(contenido) {
    var elemento = document.getElementById('contenido-archivo');
    elemento.innerHTML = contenido;
  }
  document.getElementById('file-input')
    .addEventListener('change', CargarClientes, false);
</script>

<body>

  <body>
    <table cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0>
      <thead>
        <th>Nombre</th>
        <th>Apellido</th>
        <th>Cedula</th>
        <th>Telefono</th>
        <th>Correo Electronico</th>
        <tr>
          <td class='phpcolor'>Huron</td>
          <td class='phpcolor'>SD</td>
          <td class='phpcolor'>1281</td>
          <td class='phpcolor'>100</td>
          <td class='phpcolor'>-30</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class='phpcolor'>Rapid&nbsp;City</td>
          <td class='phpcolor'>SD</td>
          <td class='phpcolor'>3162</td>
          <td class='phpcolor'>106</td>
          <td class='phpcolor'>-30</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Do you want show a table data with javascript from txt?

Comment: are you forced to have your txt file in any certain format?

Comment: we are trying to help can you please respond?

Comment: Sorry, i was a little busy, and to be honest, i wasn't expecting so much help, i really thank you guys very much. Answering the questions: Do you want show a table data with javascript from txt? A: yes, for a homework/ are you forced to have your txt file in any certain format?A: I don't think so, part of the idea is for the txt file to be update by people who don't know how to program, so they can change the information on the table.

Comment: we are trying to help can you please respond?A: I really do apologize, this is my first time posting a question online, and i always guessed it took like a couple of days to be helped, and i posted this while i was at work so i wasn't able to check again because i work at a call center and we were having a lot of calls today.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The magic happens once I turn the contents of your txt file into an `object`

You can make your file into object notation `JSON` with a simple method of `JSON.stringify(nameOfObject)` and it would be easier turned back into an object with `JSON.parse(nameOfObject)`

Instead I turned the txt file into

```
nombre=["Mario","Roberto"];
apellido=["Atencio","Icaza"];
cedula=["8-782-2289","8-582-2149"];
telefono=["233-7867","393-5517"];
correo=["matencio@misitio.com","ricaza@miweb.com"];
```

And then I turn that into an object via

```
e.target.result.split('\n').forEach(a=>{
  eval('obj.'+a); //turns the txt file data into an object
});
```

Now as to the full code, take a look

```js
function CargarClientes(e) { 
  var obj={};
  var archivo = e.target.files[0];
  if (!archivo) {
    return;
  }
  var lector = new FileReader();
  lector.onload = function(e) { //table making
    e.target.result.split('\n').forEach(a=>{
      eval('obj.'+a); //turns the txt file data into an object
    });
    var myTable=document.createElement('table');
    myTable.cellPadding=0; myTable.cellSpacing=0;
    myTable.appendChild(document.createElement('thead'));
    
    for(var i=0; i<obj[Object.keys(obj)[0]].length; i++){
      myTable.tHead.appendChild(document.createElement('tr'));
    }
    Object.keys(obj).forEach(a=>{ //everything besides the "head"
      for(var i=0; i<myTable.tHead.childElementCount; i++){
        var myData=document.createElement('td');
        myData.innerText=obj[a][i];
        myData.className="phpcolor";
        myTable.tHead.childNodes[i].appendChild(myData);
      }
    });
    Object.keys(obj).forEach(a=>{ //the "head"
      var myData=document.createElement('th');
      myData.innerText=a;
      myTable.tHead.insertBefore(myData,myTable.tHead.childNodes[0]);
    });
    document.body.appendChild(myTable); //table placing
  };
  lector.readAsText(archivo);
}


document.getElementById('file-input').addEventListener('change', CargarClientes, false);
```

```css
    table {
      width: 80%;
      border: 1px solid #fff;
      box-shadow: -18px -8px 20px #ccc;
      margin-left: 13%;
    }
    
    tr {
      width: 100%;
    }
    
    td {
      background: transparent;
      width: 10%;
      border-top: 1px solid #003;
      border-right: none;
      border-left: none;
      font: 62% Arial, Helvetica;
      padding: 6px;
      text-align: right;
    }
    
    th {
      font: 62% Arial, Helvetica;
      background: #8ADBFE;
      color: #FFFFFF
    }
    
    .phpcolor {
      text-align: center;
      background: #CBCBCB;
      color: #BDEBFE
    }
```

```html
<input type="file" id="file-input" />
<h3>Contenido del archivo:</h3>
<pre id="contenido-archivo"></pre>
```

I have a repl https://repl.it/join/dofekwzf-paultaylor2 incase it doesn't work here

Comment: Thank you very much, this was really helpful.